# Python/IPython strange non reproducible list index out of range error

Tags: python, indexing, changelist

I have recently been learning some Python and how to apply it to my work. I have written a couple of scripts successfully, but I am having an issue I just cannot figure out.

I am opening a file with ~4000 lines, two tab separated columns per line. When reading the input file, I get an index error saying that the list index is out of range. However, while I get the error every time, it doesn't happen on the same line every time (as in, it will throw the error on different lines everytime!). So, for some reason, it works generally but then (seemingly) randomly fails.

As I literally only started learning Python last week, I am stumped. I have looked around for the same problem, but not found anything similar. Furthermore I don't know if this is a problem that is language specific or IPython specific. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
input = open("count.txt", "r")
changelist = []
listtosort = []
second = str()

output = open("output.txt", "w")

for each in input:
    splits = each.split("\t")
    changelist = list(splits[0])
    second = int(splits[1])

print second

if changelist[7] == ";":   
    changelist.insert(6, "000")
    va = "".join(changelist) 
    var = va + ("\t") + str(second)
    listtosort.append(var)
    output.write(var)

elif changelist[8] == ";":   
    changelist.insert(6, "00")
    va = "".join(changelist) 
    var = va + ("\t") + str(second)
    listtosort.append(var)
    output.write(var)

elif changelist[9] == ";":   
    changelist.insert(6, "0")
    va = "".join(changelist) 
    var = va + ("\t") + str(second)
    listtosort.append(var)
    output.write(var)

else:
    #output.write(str("".join(changelist)))
    va = "".join(changelist)
    var = va + ("\t") + str(second)
    listtosort.append(var)
    output.write(var)

output.close()
```

The error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/a/Desktop/sharedfolder/ipytest/individ.ins.count.test/<ipython-input-87-32f9b0a1951b> in <module>()
     57     splits = each.split("\t")
     58     changelist = list(splits[0])
---> 59     second = int(splits[1])
     60 
     61     print second

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Input:

```
ID=cds0;Name=NP_414542.1;Parent=gene0;Dbxref=ASAP:ABE-0000006,UniProtKB%2FSwiss-Prot:P0AD86,Genbank:NP_414542.1,EcoGene:EG11277,GeneID:944742;gbkey=CDS;product=thr 12
ID=cds1000;Name=NP_415538.1;Parent=gene1035;Dbxref=ASAP:ABE-0003451,UniProtKB%2FSwiss-Prot:P31545,Genbank:NP_415538.1,EcoGene:EG11735,GeneID:946500;gbkey=CDS;product=deferrrochelatase%2C  50
ID=cds1001;Name=NP_415539.1;Parent=gene1036;Note=PhoB-dependent%2C  36
```

Desired output:

```
ID=cds0000;Name=NP_414542.1;Parent=gene0;Dbxref=ASAP:ABE-0000006,UniProtKB%2FSwiss-Prot:P0AD86,Genbank:NP_414542.1,EcoGene:EG11277,GeneID:944742;gbkey=CDS;product=thr  12
ID=cds1000;Name=NP_415538.1;Parent=gene1035;Dbxref=ASAP:ABE-0003451,UniProtKB%2FSwiss-Prot:P31545,Genbank:NP_415538.1,EcoGene:EG11735,GeneID:946500;gbkey=CDS;product=deferrrochelatase%2C  50
ID=cds1001;Name=NP_415539.1;Parent=gene1036;Note=PhoB-dependent%2C  36
```

Comment: Could you provide some example input and expected output?

Comment: Please edit this information to your question.

Comment: Sorry, inexperienced!

Comment: Are you sure it's a `\t` and not just any whitespace that's delimiting the columns?

Comment: I really don't know...the thing that is confusing me is that some lines which come up with the error some times, don't come up with the error other times. I run exactly the same code multiple times and get the error at a different position each time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `IndexError` is that your input-file is apparently not entirely tab delimited. That's why there is nothing at `splits[1]` when you attempt to access it.

Your code could use some refactoring. First of all you're repeating yourself with the `if`-checks, it's unnecessary. This just pads the `cds0` to 7 characters which is probably not what you want. I threw the following together to demonstrate how you could refactor your code to be a little more pythonic and dry. I can't guarantee it'll work with your dataset, but I'm hoping it might help you understand how to do things differently.

```
    to_sort = []
    # We can open two files using the with statement. This will also handle 
    # closing the files for us, when we exit the block.
    with open("count.txt", "r") as inp, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
        for each in inp:
           # Split at ';'... So you won't have to worry about whether or not
           # the file is tab delimited
           changed = each.split(";")

           # Get the value you want. This is called unpacking.
           # The value before '=' will always be 'ID', so we don't really care about it.
           # _ is generally used as a variable name when the value is discarded.
           _, value = changed[0].split("=")

           # 0-pad the desired value to 7 characters. Python string formatting
           # makes this very easy. This will replace the current value in the list.
           changed[0] = "ID={:0<7}".format(value)

           # Join the changed-list with the original separator and
           # and append it to the sort list.
           to_sort.append(";".join(changed))

       # Write the results to the file all at once. Your test data already
       # provided the newlines, you can just write it out as it is.
       output.writelines(to_sort)

       # Do what else you need to do. Maybe to_list.sort()?
```

You'll notice that this code is reduces your code down to 8 lines but achieves the exact same thing, does not repeat itself and is pretty easy to understand.

Please read the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the [Zen](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) of python, and go through the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and input! I've tried your code and it works, but the numbering isn't quite right. The input contains values such as cds0/cds10/cds100 which need to be cds0000/cds0010/cds0100 to sort them by, and other than my code above I couldn't think of any other way to implement it...I still have much to learn!

Comment: Without knowing anything about the ID's, the `cds0/cds10/cds100` is a sortable sequence in itself. The final implementation will depend on the number of possible values you have. I suggest you take a look at the [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a line in count.txt which doesn't contain the tab character. So when you split by tab character there will not be any `splits[1]`. Hence the error "Index out of range".

To know which line is causing the error, just add a `print(each)` after `splits` in line 57. The line printed before the error message is your culprit. If your input file keeps changing, then you will get different locations. Change your script to handle such malformed lines.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I will try to follow your advice...fingers crossed!